# Problem: XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<!DOCTYP'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I use jupyter notebook for practice fond errors. The following are my codes:

```
from __future__ import print_function import numpy as np import
pandas as pd
    
!pip install xlrd print('xlrd installed!')
    
df_can = pd.read_excel(
    'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WXk5iJShM34JcLNJbOjWu2p4excYAzhd/view?usp=sharing',sheetname="UN population", skiprows=range(17), skip_footer = 2 )
df_can.head()
```

here are the errors:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<!DOCTYP'
```

Comment: That URL is not leading to an XLS file, it serves up a Google drive wrapper.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this. If I want to download a .xlsx file , what can I do?

Comment: I'm just reporting on what I see served from that URL.

Comment: Are you using google colab or running jupyter notebook on local computer?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0h5ysfoooq1yjm4wpta0f/UN_population.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=oyekur5do3x4o1h4ru4bkcmol

Comment: To techytushar : I use Jupyter notebook on local computer, I guess?

Comment: Okay. I solved the problem. Thanks for all of your help!^-^  [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11A_ZovvKB4mr-a29NbgHwhiC_uSeapSzPz5nUwCuVjk/export?format=xlsx)